# Is it possible to send a get request with JSON body in Axios?

Tags: reactjs, express, http, axios, fetch

Get requests with JSON body option available in postman. but, How to send a body with get request in Axios?

Comment: You can certainly type a JSON body into the UI of Postman for a GET request, but does it actually send the body as part of the request?

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) from 2009, it might shed some light for you on why axios wouldn't include a body property in a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you really shouldn't. Get requests are meant to be useful by just passing the url with query parameters when applicable. Either way, the method signature is for `axios.get` is

```
get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
```

You can use it like this

```
const data: { ... }; // your payload, replace (...) for actual data
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = { data };

axios.get('/your-endpoint', config);
```